# AC Current Source - Modifiable Amplitude and Frequency

Tags: ac, current-source

Just a heads up, I am not an electrical engineer. I need to build an AC current source of the following specifications. I have looked into IC chips, but none meet my specifications. I have started looking into the Howland Current Pump circuits and audio amplifiers.

**Specifications:**

1. **Amplitude of AC Current:**

   0 - 1A (peak to peak). Should be able to change the amplitude.
2. **Frequency of AC Current:**

   0 to 75 kHz. Should be able to set the frequency as well.
3. **Load:**

   Copper coil with a resistance of 0.5 Ohms and 5000 nH inductance.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to know if there is a way to change the amplitude and frequency of the output current when using a Howland Current Pump circuit.
2. My load is a coil and is inductive. I have read that the Howland circuit becomes unstable for inductive loads. Any advice on how to make it stable.
3. Any other alternative circuits that can meet specs?

Comment: Install a resistor of 10 to 15 ohms between the power source and the coil. It isolates the back-EMF of the coil, and the source now 'sees' it as a dampened inductor. Yes, it is a compromise, but you get some of what you want.

Comment: Just want to be sure: by saying 1 A peak to peak do you mean \$\pm 500\:\text{mA}\$? Or did you really mean \$\pm 1000\:\text{mA}\$? Or do you mean 0 to +1, as in "an average DC offset of +0.5?" And why can't you consider an appropriate audio amplifier output stage (bridged, or not) driven by a COTS signal generator?

Comment: @jonk It should be +/- 500mA, although an offset is not an issue. Can you suggest an appropriate audio amplifier that can drive an amp of current into the coil?

Comment: @Sparky256 So the power source is an AC voltage signal which is routed through a 10 ohm resistor? Unfortunately I do not understand what you mean by "source now 'sees' it as a dampened inductor". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RyanLocke Frequencies at or below \$75\:\text{kHz}\$ are well within the usual range of the output stages of power audio amplifiers. If you look at class-AB output stages and perhaps consider the idea of a *bridged* arrangement (such as with the TDA8551, for example) then you might get something workable with COTS parts. The TDA8551 supports up to an amp as a "epetitive peak output current." So although it is designed more for \$8\:\Omega\$ speakers, it's possible the device could be applied here. (You should examine it to see if it might be possible.)